# Postgres failing to consistently use best partial indexes when multiple are present

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, execution-plan, postgresql-performance

In Postgres 10.17, I have two queries with different `WHERE` clauses and two partial indexes (`idx_s_id` and `idx_w_id`) optimized for each one respectively that should allow index only scans for both queries. However, the Postgres query planner always uses EITHER the first OR the second index for BOTH queries which always causes one of the two to run suboptimally (i.e. as a regular index scan rather than an index only scan).

These indexes are high churn and therefore bloat quickly and, interestingly, I've figured out that I can make the query planner switch both queries over to `idx_s_id` (or `idx_w_id`) by reindexing it after a day of use. However, even immediately after reindexing both, Postgres will still only choose one... and not necessarily not the smaller of the two (e.g. most recently the query planner chose `idx_s_id` even though it was 40 kB and `idx_w_id` was 32 kB).

Another curious thing is that the cost estimates for the two queries are the same despite the obvious differences between their plans and I definitely don't understand why.

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how to convince postgres to use the correct index in both cases?

### TABLE

```
          Column           |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |                      Default
---------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------------
 a_id                      | integer                     |           | not null | nextval('tbl_a_id_seq'::regclass)
 state                     | character varying(100)      |           | not null |
 w_id                      | integer                     |           | not null |
 s_id                      | integer                     |           |          |
...
```

### INDEXES

```
"idx_s_id" UNIQUE, btree (s_id, a_id) WHERE state::text = 'AT_AGENT'::text

"idx_w_id" UNIQUE, btree (w_id, a_id) WHERE state::text = 'AT_AGENT'::text
```

### QUERIES

```
SELECT a_id
  FROM tbl
 WHERE state = 'AT_AGENT' AND s_id = 14941529 AND a_id != 10 LIMIT 1;

SELECT a_id
  FROM tbl
 WHERE state = 'AT_AGENT' AND w_id = 3809609 AND a_id != 10 LIMIT 1;
```

### EXPLAIN ANALYZES BEFORE REINDEX

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT a_id
  FROM tbl
 WHERE state = 'AT_AGENT' AND s_id = 14941529 AND a_id != 10 LIMIT 1;
                                                                   QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.42..2.44 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=31.503..31.504 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using idx_w_id on tbl  (cost=0.42..2.44 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=31.502..31.502 rows=0 loops=1)
         Filter: ((a_id <> 10) AND (s_id = 14941529))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 716
 Planning time: 0.198 ms
 Execution time: 31.525 ms
(6 rows)
```

AND

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT a_id
  FROM tbl
 WHERE state = 'AT_AGENT' AND w_id = 3809609 AND a_id != 10 LIMIT 1;
                                                                        QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.42..2.44 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using idx_w_id on tbl  (cost=0.42..2.44 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=0 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (w_id = 3809609)
         Filter: (a_id <> 10)
         Heap Fetches: 2
 Planning time: 0.137 ms
 Execution time: 0.041 ms
(7 rows)
```

### EXPLAIN ANALYZES AFTER REINDEXING IDX_W_ID

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT a_id
  FROM tbl
 WHERE state = 'AT_AGENT' AND s_id = 14941529 AND a_id != 10 LIMIT 1;
                                                                       QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.28..2.28 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using idx_s_id on tbl  (cost=0.28..2.28 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=0 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (s_id = 14941529)
         Filter: (a_id <> 10)
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 0.792 ms
 Execution time: 0.035 ms
(7 rows)
```

AND

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT a_id
  FROM tbl
 WHERE state = 'AT_AGENT' AND w_id = 3809609 AND a_id != 10 LIMIT 1;
                                                                     QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.28..2.28 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.693..1.693 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using idx_s_id on tbl  (cost=0.28..2.28 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1.691..1.691 rows=0 loops=1)
         Filter: ((a_id <> 10) AND (w_id = 3809609))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 717
 Planning time: 0.210 ms
 Execution time: 1.712 ms
(6 rows)
```

### DB COST PARAMETERS

```
 Setting                        Current Value   Default Value   Source
  ------------------------------ --------------- --------------- --------------------
  cpu_index_tuple_cost           0.005           0.005           default
  cpu_operator_cost              0.0025          0.0025          default
  cpu_tuple_cost                 0.01            0.01            default
  effective_cache_size           302 GB          4 GB            configuration file
  min_parallel_index_scan_size   512 KB          512 KB          default
  min_parallel_table_scan_size   8 MB            8 MB            default
  parallel_setup_cost            1,000           1,000           default
  parallel_tuple_cost            0.1             0.1             default
  random_page_cost               1               4               configuration file
  seq_page_cost                  1               1               configuration file
```

Comment: Postgres 10. Latest point release? ([Currently 10.17.](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)) Is upgrading to a current version an option? (Postgres 13, soon to be 14) `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` may be more revealing. And you are aware that `s_id = REDACTED` is futile when the ID is disclosed in the query plan anyway? Finally, what happens immediately after `VACUUM ANALYZE tbl`? Visibility or column statistic might play a role.

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Do you have non-standard settings for the cost parameters?

Comment: @jjanes I updated the post with our cost parameters

Comment: Even with `random_page_cost = 1` (which seems like a ridiculous setting, even for top-of-the-line SSD.  Try something like 1.1) I still can't reproduce this.